# Existence of a particular element in $U(n)$ the unit group of integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $U(n)$ is the group of all the units in $\mathbb Z_n$. If $n>2$, prove that there is an element in $U(n)$ such that $k^2 = 1$ and $k\neq 1$. (From the 2013 edition of *Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications* by Thomas W. Judson.)

There is a Cayley table in the book that shows that in $U(8)$ each element is its own inverse, but I don't understand why. In any case, if this is true I can just choose $k$ to be any element in the set that is not even.

Comment: Hint: Can you find an integer $n$ (not necessarily positive) such that $n^2 = 1$ and $n\neq 1$?

Comment: -1? I don't see how knowing that helps since n > 2

Comment: Since $n>2$ then $1\ne -1$.

Comment: How does it not help? Why should $n> 2$ mean this was not an example?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I think there may be some confusion regarding the choice of letters $n$ and $k$.

Comment: @String Ahh, good catch. Replace $n$ by $k$ in my hint.